# task scheduler wont run program when logged off, program is otherwise self sufficient

Tags: c#, authentication, scheduled-tasks, task

I just wrote a program but I want to automate it and run it at a certain time every day.  However I will be stepping away from my computer for a week.  I need the task scheduler to `wake to run task` which seems to work fine for me, and I need it to `run whether logged on or not` and this is the thing that is not working.

My program needs to be able to open a web browser.  So when I ran this with `user must be logged on`, it was unable to open the browser even though I woke to the login screen.  However, once I check the `run whether logged on or not` it seems to not run.  I have looked into "non-interactive mode" but I dont understand how this affects my particular type of program that requires a browser to open.

does anyone know how I could get around this?  Maybe have a separate task that logs in first, then a task just after, that runs the program.  My program is in c# by the way.

Comment: Does it need to "open a web browser" or does it need to make a connection to a web server? Is the browser an essential part of this problem or just a means to an end?

Comment: that is a fine question.  One that will require some research on my part.  I will say this:  At the moment a web browser is necessary.  However, it could very well just be a means to my end that I am unaware of. I will look into it and report it back here when I find out

Comment: Have you looked into designing your project as a Windows Service so that you don't need to rely on the Scheduled Task infrastructure?

Comment: oh? I didnt know that I could fiddle with Windows Services.  Could you maybe point me towards the api for services?